# IndexOf(), String index out of bounds: -1

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have no idea what is happening. I have a list of products along with a number separated with a tab. When I use `indexOf()` to find the tab, I get a `String index out of bounds error`, and it says the `index` is -1. Here's the code:

```
package taxes;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Taxes {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //File aFile = new File("H:\\java\\PrimeNumbers\\build\\classes\\primenumbers\\priceList.txt");
        File aFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Tim\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Taxes\\src\\taxes\\priceList.txt");
        priceChange(aFile);
    }

    static void priceChange(File inFile) throws IOException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner("priceList.txt");
        char tab = '\t';
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            int a = line.indexOf(tab);
            String productName = line.substring(0,a);
            String priceTag = line.substring(a);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the input:

```
Plyer set   10
Jaw Locking Plyers  10
Cable Cutter    7
16 oz. Hammer   5
64 oz. Dead Blow Hammer 12
Sledge Hammer   20
Cordless Drill  22
Hex Impact Driver 50
Drill Bit Set   30
Miter Saw   200
Circular Saw    40
```

Comment: does tab contain in `Jaw Locking Plyers  10`

Comment: yeah it's there, it's just that moving it messed with the formatting a bit

Comment: find in which line of txt file error occurred .

Comment: @Tim Please see my updated answer. Let me know if that answers your questions.

Comment: it gets the error after reading the first line, but it seems to be that all lines don't work

Comment: @Steve It does, I tried putting an if-statement around the substring, so if it's -1 for that line, it won't do anything. Now it runs through the entire input and doesn't do anything. Do you think Java is unable to read a tab as a character?

Comment: Try Tom's suggestion. You want the scanner to read File inFile that's being passed into the parameter. Therefore, do new Scanner(inFile) instead. @Tim

Comment: @Tim "Do you think Java is unable to read a tab as a character?" No, I don't think that's the case.

Comment: I did inFile, and it is definitely reading the correct file now, but I'm still getting the same error :/

Comment: @Tim Maybe try to do double quotes and declare it as a string instead?

Comment: String tab = "\t";  @Tim

Comment: If I do that it says that I can't convert the string ("\t") to a char (tab).

Comment: can't you just declare it a string? @Tim

Comment: Usage of `'\t'` is fine. I guess the file (or at least one line) doesn't contain a tab. Maybe it has substituted whitespaces. This happens if the file was created with an IDE which has such a setting.

Comment: Meaning if it's not exactly a tab, but some whitespaces? Yes that's possible. @Tom

Comment: @Tom I'm using Netbeans and I haven't set that as an option, unless it's default. Also, when I move my cursor back and forth, it jumps across, so clearly it must be a tab and not a bunch of spaces

Comment: @Steve Some IDE have a setting where you can replace any tab character with a certain amount of whitespace to ensure the same look on every computer without mentioning the tab setting. If that text file was created with such an IDE, then the tab could have been replaced with whitespaces.

Comment: @Tim you could open your text file with a text editor like notepad++ just to make sure, that it is really a tab. I've never used Netbeans, so I don't know how it behaves.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949014/how-can-i-configure-netbeans-to-insert-tabs-instead-of-a-bunch-of-spaces  I unchecked the option that the first answer suggested, but it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: First, make sure that your code works by inserting the tabs with a different program, then bother Netbeans with the right setting :).

Comment: @Tim Try testing your code with something other than '\n', to make sure your algorithm works the way you want to. Try finding the letter 'l' or something.

Comment: @Steve YAAAAY. Thank god, that was killing me. I replaced the tab with a "-" and it worked.

Comment: @Tim  Great! Your code is correct, then.

Comment: Well, as I said, the tabs got replaced :P.

Answer (score 3):

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner("priceList.txt");
```

This line of code is wrong. This Scanner instance will scan the String `"priceList.txt"`. It doesn't contain a tab, therefore `indexOf` returns `-1`.

Change it to:

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(inFile);
```

to use the method argument, that is the desired file instance of your *priceList.txt*.

Comment: I changed that, but I think it is still unable to find a tab

Comment: But it definitely is reading the actual file I want, thank you.

Comment: A small test with the updated code of your question proofs, that your code will work then. Make sure that the file *really* contains tabs and not substituted whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

`String.indexOf(char)` will return -1 if an instance isn't found.

You need to check before proceeding that `a` isn't negative.

You can read more about the `indexOf` method [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)).

Comment: But the tab does exist, why can it not find it?

Comment: After the line `String line = scan.nextLine();` write `System.out.println(line);`. Then at least you'll know which line doesn't contain tab.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are checking `int a = line.indexOf(tab)` in every iteration of the while loop, there has to be a **tab** in every single line of your document in order for the error to be prevented.
When your `while (scan.hasNextLine())` loop runs into a line with no tab in it, the index is going to be -1, and you get the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` when trying to get `line.substring(0,a)`, with `a` being -1.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    int a = line.indexOf(tab);
    if(a!=-1) {
        String productName = line.substring(0,a);
        String priceTag = line.substring(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this and the program returned nothing. I guess that means there are no tabs in the input? I tried redoing the tabs and that did nothing. Is tab an unreadable character or something?

Answer (score 0):

If you look very carefully at the input lines you have posted, you'll see

```
Jaw Locking Plyers  10
...
Cordless Drill  22
Hex Impact Driver 50
Drill Bit Set   30
```

that the "Hex Impact Driver" line has the price two characters to the right of the one in the lines before and after. This is an indication that "50" does not start at a tab position whereas "10" is at such a position, the next after the one for "22" and "30".

The Q&A editor does preserve TABs, so your editor preserves them as well, and your program should be able to recognize a TAB in the input lines.

That said, a TAB entered by hand (!) is a very poor choice for a separator. As you have experienced, text file presentation doesn't show it. It would be much better to use a special character that does not occur in the product names. Plausible choices are '|', '#', and '\'.

Another good way would be to use pattern matching to find the numeric price at the end of a line - the product name is what remains after removing the price and calling trim() on the remaining string.

Answer (score 0):

Since it has been verified that indexOf(tab) returns -1, the question is why does the line of text **not contain t a tab** when you seem certain that it does?

The answer is most likely the settings on your IDE. For instance, I usually configure Netbeans to convert a tab to three spaces. So if you typed this input file yourself within an IDE, the tab-to-space conversion is likely the problem.
[image: Netbeans editor option dialog]

**Work around:**

1. If we copy/paste some text into Netbeans that includes tabs, the tabs do not get converted to spaces.
2. The text file could be created with notepad or any other simple text editor to avoid the problem.
3. Change the settings on your IDE, at least for this project.