# How to convert spaces in tabs in Netbeans 8.2?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-8.2

Some IDEs and Text Editors write spaces instead of TABs.

1. Is there a way to convert these spaces into TABs when I import a project or some files in Netbeans 8.2 ?
2. Is there a way to convert spaces into TABs for a Netbeans current project?

I also saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949014/how-can-i-configure-netbeans-to-insert-tabs-instead-of-a-bunch-of-spaces) about the Editor settings but it doesn't solve my problem.

Maybe this feature [it has always been missing](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=143795)?

If you don't know how to solve this issue using NetBeans, other solutions are welcome.

(Please upvote if you consider this answer relevant :) )

Comment: [1] There is no way to convert spaces to TABs during an import. [2] Regarding your comment "it doesn't solve my problem", can you please clarify what didn't solve your problem? Do you mean unchecking "Expand tabs to spaces" did not solve your problem? [3] What was the language for the file you were editing to convert spaces to TABs? Java? HTML?

Answer (score 2):

When you uncheck "Expand Tabs to Spaces" (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949014/how-can-i-configure-netbeans-to-insert-tabs-instead-of-a-bunch-of-spaces)) you can then use Code -> Format (or SHIFT-ALT-F) to convert your spaces to tabs.
See [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=143795) for more information.

The prolem with this approach is that it also applies other formatting to your code, that you may not want (that is my case).

Comment: thank you for writing this answer. I was struggling with the tabs and space issues for few months but never care to search it online. I am glad to find this answer today.